# Is it ever posible to win if the only pieces left are two kings and a knight?

Tags: checkmate

If the only pieces left on the board are the two kings and a knight, is it ever possible to force check mate? I mean, if the bare king avoids the edges and stays close to the opponent's knight, I don't see how the game can ever end. I was in this situation for more than half an hour yesterday and we were forced to draw.

Comment: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/is-it-possible-to-checkmate-with-knight-and-king-against-king

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, it is not possible.**

The knight simply does not cover enough space to checkmate the black king.
When a position with insufficient material to checkmate occurs, **a draw by insufficient material** is declared.

**Draw by insufficient material is declared when, and only when:**

K vs K

K + N vs K

K + B vs K

Technically, a king and 2 knights versus a lone king can still result in checkmate. However, here the black king has to be dumb enough to cooperate and go into a corner and be checkmated. And so it is usually declared a draw by insufficient material.

Comment: I think in the OP's scenario, a helpmate would be possible.  If White has a king at h8 and knight at f5, and Black has a king at f7, and knight at h4 (a position the players could easily cooperate to achieve), that would allow 1. Nh7 Ng6++

Comment: Ooops.. I misread the question as both players having a king and knight each, which is an interesting scenario.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to checkmate with a lone knight (K+N vs K). 
However, Add another Bishop and you'll be able to Checkmate (K+N+B vs K)

There is a rule in Chess which goes like this ***"No Mating material = Draw"***

So:

K vs K = **Draw**

K+N Vs K = **Draw**

K+B Vs K = **Draw**